# Why can't I view details on my files in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

When I select ANY file on my Google Drive to view its details it looks like this:

[image]

Doesn't matter what type of file I select or where on the drive it is located. It used to work a couple of days ago, for at least some files.

Using Firefox with quite a few extensions on a Mac.

Including the exact string in case someone searches for it:

"Couldn't load details. Try again."

Comment: Have you tried with another browser?  Have you tried in private mode?

Answer (score 4):

I'm encountering this issue as well, and it seems it might be an issue with cookies and especially so if you are logged into multiple user accounts in the same browser.

I verified this by logging into the same account and checking details for the same file on my normal browser window as well as the private browser window. The file details are visible in the private browser window.

Normal Browsing: [image: Error in the normal browsing mode]

Private Browsing:   [image: No error in the private browsing mode]

There seems to be no fix as such, apart from using private browsing for drive. I have tried clearing browser cache and cookies, as well as signing out and back in. None of them fixed the issue. All the extensions I have in normal browsing are also enabled in private browsing (ublock origin, dark reader, bypass paywalls and tab session manager). Your mileage may vary. Ultimately this is a Google issue and needs to be solved by them at their back-end.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/153950)

Comment: This is helpful: I'm also having this issue but never realized multiple active accounts could be a problem. Doesn't fix the problem, but may be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also have been having this problem since late 2022, and have determined that it occurs only with Firefox.  The Activity displays correctly, but not the file Details. It doesn't seem to matter who owns the files, none of the Details are displayed.

I downloaded Chrome and do not have the problem with that browser, nor with Microsoft Edge.  I didn't like always needing to use the private Firefox browser window whenever I access Drive folders, which I do a lot.  I don't know if this is a Google issue or a Firefox issue, or just an example of not playing together nicely anymore.

So I have resigned myself to using Chrome for accessing Google Drive.  I know this isn't really an answer, just a workaround.  But I don't want to give up Firefox, and I use Dashlane which doesn't have a Chrome extension. So I don't want to switch to Chrome entirely.

Using Firefox 109.0 (64-bit) with Windows 10 on a desktop Dell.  I am a non-techie user, a novice to StackExchange. I'm not really willing to bend over backwards to solve this.  Wanting to see such metadata about my Google Drive files doesn't seem unreasonable to me.

Comment: PROBLEM FIXED?
The metadata for this question says it was updated yesterday, but I couldn't figure out where. 
However, my Firefox version is now 109.0.1 and I am able to see the Google Drive file details again! I don't know if the browser update addressed the problem or if Google changed something. But the original poster might want to see if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried doing this on my own Google Drive and had no issues. Why? To make sure it wasn't an issue on their platform.
With that said, there are a few things you can try.

1. Are any of the files you have tried ones you own? Asking this because we often have files in our drives where it has a different owner. They control what other users can and cannot see. I realize it seems like a dumb question, but wanted to ask up front. If you are unsure, create a document while in your Google Drive. There should be a button top left that says "New". Click it and create a new document. You can put junk into the document's title and body. After you are done, make sure it states it is saved and you can close out. Back in your main area of your drive, go down to that new test document and click once on it. The details on it should pop up on the right side. If you still can't see any details? You are correct that it isn't you but something else going on.
2. Is your Firefox browser fully updated? Sometimes a browser, any browser, can run into issues if it hasn't received all its updates on your device.
   I run Windows and can't speak to Mac specifically. But I did do my test of my own drive in both the Firefox browser and Chrome browser.
3. Try downloading and using Chrome browser. Don't add anything else, any extensions, when you do so. This way you can validate it isn't related to an add-on or extension.

Lastly, here is a link to Google support's suggestions on how to fix common issues in Google Drive. It discusses the issue you are running into as well.
https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2456903?hl=en

Hope some part of my response helps you. Sorry you are running into this. I know how frustrating it can be.

Answer (score -2):

The easy and useful method of relaunching Google sync. Also you can follow up with these methods that will help to resolve it.

Running Google Backup App as Admin
Changing Some Firewall Settings
Additional fixes
Resign in

To know more detail of this issue can check out [this article](https://silicophilic.com/google-drive-folders-not-showing-up/). Hope it will help to resolve it.

Comment: At this point, it seems most of your answer is hidden behind a link. Links can rot. Please consider adding the relevant information to your answer. If you are affiliated with the page in any way, please disclose this as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).